# POJO has a byte[] field, but JSON corresponding to it has string field. How to convert the string to byte[]?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My POJO has the following structure:

```
class SomeName
{
       .... // some fields
       private byte[] message;
       ....
       .... // some functions
       public byte[] getMessage() 
       {
           return message;
       }
}
```

And my JSON file has the field named 'message' which has a String stored in it. Currently I am using ObjectMapper from *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper*. The syntax being

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeName myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonData, new TypeReference<SomeName>() {});
```

Is there a way with this solution or an alternate solution (other than tampering the POJO or the JSON) for this?

Comment: This is to be expected as you cannot send binary data in json format. Jackson encodes your binary data to Base64, this is the value you see in your json result

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this way using GSON Liberary. If you are not stick to jackson library. Hope you will get your answer from this part.

```
 public class JsonParse
 {
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Employee product = new Employee("JSON");
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
        gson = new 
        GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        String result = gson.toJson(product);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
 }

class Employee
{

  @Expose
  private byte [] name;

  public Employee(String name)
  {
     this.name = name.getBytes();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example using GSON custom deserializer:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

class GsonStringToBytesExample {
    // POJO
    static class SomeName {
      public byte[] message;
    }

    // custom deserializer capable of converting json string field to pojo's byte[] field
    static class SomeNameDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<SomeName> {
      private final static Gson gson = new Gson();

      @Override
      public SomeName deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // reading json fields to map
        Map<String, JsonElement> fieldsMap = json.getAsJsonObject().asMap();
        // reading json string message
        String messageStr = fieldsMap.get("message").getAsString();
        // creating bytes array from string
        byte[] messageBytes = messageStr.getBytes();
        // creating GSON's JsonElement from bytes array
        JsonElement dataBytesJsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(messageBytes);
        // substituting json "message" field with bytes array object
        fieldsMap.put("message", dataBytesJsonElement);
        // finally deserializing to POJO
        return gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = """
            {"message":"hi"}
            """;

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            // registering custom deserializer
            .registerTypeAdapter(SomeName.class, new SomeNameDeserializer())
            .create();

    SomeName someName = gson.fromJson(json, SomeName.class);
    // here we have pojo with bytes array from string
    System.out.println(new String(someName.message));
  }
}
```